Langgraph -SQL create_react_agent - SQLDatabaseToolkit -- Skip After SQL execution
I am Currently doing a POC on chatbot that uses SQLs for user response. Seeking your guidance regarding a scenario involving create_react_agent. My intent is to use 2 LLMs, a currently advanced LLM like 'GPT 4 32k' for SQL generation and some cost-effective LLM for user response construction. So far I am not successful in breaking the create_react_agent flow(right after SQL Execution). Following is the concerned code block.
def get_response(state: gr.State, user_input: str, history: list)->any:

toolkit = SQLDatabaseToolkit(db=DB, llm=LLM)
tools = toolkit.get_tools()
system_message = SystemMessage(content=SQL_PREFIX)  
agent_executor = create_react_agent(LLM, tools, messages_modifier=system_message)           
for s in agent_executor.stream(
                {"messages": [HumanMessage(content=user_input)]}, stream_mode="values"
            ):
                
                message = s["messages"][-1]
                if isinstance(message, tuple):
                    print(message)
                    response = message.content
                else:
                    message.pretty_print()
                    response = message.content

history.append((user_input, response))
return ["", history]

create_react_agent has a parameter "Interrupt_after". Although I am quite unsure of its usage / implementation.
Please share your ideas on how to proceed here.

I don't know if you have solved yet, but keep in mind the difference between LangChain and LangGraph. There are two different approaches, in my opinion , and following the documentation of both, the first one is a less advanced then the second one.
In fact of that, LangGraph you could achieve best results in customisation and performance. Said that, the official guide of LangChain offers the simple solution based on create_react_agent or another simple based on create_sql_agent. Simple for someone who never saw LangChain how it works.
Secondly LangGraph, in this specific case you could combine the framework of abstraction of LangChain, plus, the patterns of nodes-edges of LangGraph. Exactly, it works like a conditional system, if....else.
The best guide is the official available on GitHub repository, let's check it out https://github.com/langchain-ai/langgraph/blob/main/examples/tutorials/sql-agent.ipynb because, combining both architecture, you will achieve your goal, otherwise, honestly, it s**ks for the less responsive and "reacted" how it is built.
Let me know, I'm fighting with Langchain almost 10 months and it still surprising to me.
